# Apache access log "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 615 "-"

Tags: apache, symfony, http-status-code-404

When I try to enter my local symfony2 site, it is loading for a long time and then I see a white screen. In my apache access log I see this message:

```
"127.0.0.1 - - [12/May/2015:12:38:12 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 615 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36"".
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled rewrite?

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
```

This will allow you to view [domain]/

Otherwise access at [domain]/app.php

Comment: I use <Directory /var/www/project/web>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
 </Directory>

Comment: Please update you question to include You apache config.